# socket input stuck in loop

Tags: python, loops, sockets

I working on this code and I receive an input from the socket successfully but then it breaks and keeps looping in a test loop if the wrong input is entered. I expect it to wait for another input but something is causing it to loop.  Can some one help me figure out what hanging this loop up?

code of receiving socket.

```
data = conn.recv(2042)  
line=data.decode('UTF-8')
continue_q=line
#print (continue_q)
while True:
 if continue_q !=  "y" or "Y" or "n" or "N":

    print("atgorboge")
    #continue_q = input("Please address errors. " \
    #                   "Continue? (Y/N) ")
    print("please adress errors. continue? (Y/N)")
    
    #continue_q=None
    #while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    
    data = conn.recv(2042)  
    line=data.decode('UTF-8')
    print(continue_q)
    continue_q=line
    
    #redirectOut()
 if( (continue_q == 'y') or (continue_q == 'Y') ):
     print('poped to yes')
     clear_json_flags(DEBUG_PRINT, WC)
     update_json_file(DEBUG_PRINT, CONFIG_FILE, WC)
     #redirectOut()
     return 0
 if( (continue_q == 'n') or (continue_q == 'N') ):
     print('poped to no')
     return -1
     #redirectOut()
```

out put:

```
Please address errors. Continue? (Y/N)
Socket created
None
Socket bind complete
Socket now listening
Connected to 192.168.0.11:50183
atgorboge
please adress errors. continue? (Y/N)
l
atgorboge
please adress errors. continue? (Y/N)

atgorboge
please adress errors. continue? (Y/N)

atgorboge
please adress errors. continue? (Y/N)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to sockets or loops at all.

`if continue_q !=  "y" or "Y" or "n" or "N":` always evaluates to True since it's evaluated as `if (continue_q != "y") or ("Y")...` and `"Y"` is truthy.

You'll want e.g.

```
if continue_q not in ("y", "Y", "n", "N"):
```

Beyond that, you're going to have a bad time with naive use of `conn.recv()` like that; there's no guarantee that whatever's being sent by the other end is sent in one packet (i.e. that you'll get all of the data you're expecting in one `recv()` invocation).

Comment: ya i noticed, i create a work around, and got it functioning another way. thanks for the help.